# Fantasy/sci-fi book about a boy who gets superpowers from the future

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this book a over a decade ago. and even then the book looked old. I can't say exactly when it came out. Each chapter was written in a different style. Some in first-person, some in third-person, some in debrief report style. I recall the book cover being completely blank, with no title.

The plot starts about some agents trying to track down a boy. But it turns out he is inhabited by some super being from the future. He has all sorts of superpowers including mind reading, telekinesis, healing, etc.

A big point of the story is he transfers his consciousness into some super computer and takes over all the nukes. Then he invites all the leaders of every country and threatens them to serve him.

He only trusts his psychiatrist, as she was with him as his powers were developing and knew everything. He gave her some mind reading powers to help him keep track of people. But she betrays him by secretly getting the computer to consider him a virus and purge him.

Some additional scenes I recall:

- The boy is latino. But I don't recall his name.
- His sister thought the devil inhabited him.
- His tooth filling fell out as his teeth began regenerating.
- He ran a gang and had lots of successful robberies, because he knew what not to take to not trigger alarms.
- There's a conversation about how most of history's famous people were also inhabited by future super being as well. But they specifically say Freud was not one of them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. If anyone correctly identifies the book you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].